# jQuery: ~= selector: How to get elements that *do not* contain given element in a specified tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an input field of the following type

```
<input data-of-type="football baseball basketball">
```

If I wanted to get all tags which have data-of-type "baseball", I'd use something like

```
$("[data-of-type~=baseball]")
```

However, what I want to do is get all elements that have a data-of-type set, but that data-of-type does not include baseball. In short, something like

```
$("[data-of-type!~=baseball]")
```

(which returns a syntax error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close but try this:

```
$('[data-of-type]').not("[data-of-type~=baseball]")
```

Or

```
$('[data-of-type]').filter("[data-of-type!=baseball]")
```

Or if you want:

```
$('[data-of-type][data-of-type!=baseball]')
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Answer (score 1):

If there is another common type, you can say this: `$("[data-of-type~='ball']").not("[data-of-type~=baseball]")`

or

`$("[data-of-type*='ball']").not("[data-of-type~=baseball]")`

Comment: Or just `$("[data-of-type]")` (but it also selects those elements where this attribute is empty).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using the not selector will help:

```
$("input:not[data-of-type~=baseball]")
```